# Java: Basic problems setting up a class

Tags: java, constructor, comparator

I am having some problems with the basic setup of my class.

The background:
I am writing a class which implements a MinHeap based on a binary tree.
I have a class `BinaryTree, BinaryTreeNode, MinTreeHeap, DefaultComparator` and an interface `PriorityQueue`.
`MinTreeHeap` is the class I am writing. It implements `PriorityQueue` and does some other things.
`DefaultComparator` implements functionality to compare two nodes.

A given test program calls `MinTreeHeap` with the following:

```
MinTreeHeap<Value> heap = new MinTreeHeap<>( new DefaultComparator<Value>() );
```

My problem is the class declaration of `MinTreeHeap`. I have the following so far.

```
import pa01.bintree.BinaryTree;
import pa01.bintree.BinaryTreeNode;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.NoSuchElementException;

public class MinTreeHeap<T extends DefaultComparator<T>> extends BinaryTree 
    implements PriorityQueue<T> {

  /** The actual heap. */
  private final BinaryTree<T> heap;

  /**
   * Default Constructor
   */
  public MinTreeHeap() {
    super();
    last = null;
  }

  public MinTreeHeap( T data ){
    super(data);
    last = heap.getRoot();
  }
```

I am getting errors in line `public class MinTree...`
error:

```
Bound mismatch: The type T is not a valid substitute for the bounded parameter
<T extends Comparable<T>> of the type DefaultComparator<T>
```

and I have no idea how I'm getting the functionality of my `DefaultComparator` into the class.

If you need further information to clarify just ask.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What version of JDK do you use? Try following class declaration : MinTreeHeap<X, T extends DefaultComparator<X>>

Comment: JDK 1.7 And I'm getting the same error. Eclipse points to the X in ..T extends DefaultComparator<X>>..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are confusing the type of the *data* your `MinTreeHeap` ought to store with the type of the *comparator*:

```
public class MinTreeHeap<T extends DefaultComparator<T>> extends BinaryTree
//                       ↑                           ↑
//                       |                            the type to compare
//                       A type extending the Comparator
```

Saying that `T` shall be both, a `Comparator` *and* the type of the items the `Comparator` should compare, makes no sense.

And, the `DefaultComparator` expects a type extending `Comparable` which your `T` type variable does not fulfill.

What you most probably meant is something like this:

```
public class MinTreeHeap<E, C extends Comparator<E>> extends BinaryTree 
implements PriorityQueue<E> {
```

where `E` is the type of the items to store and `C` the type of the `Comparator` (without forcing it to be a `DefaultComparator`.

It is also possible to go without a type variable for the type of the `Comparator`:

```
public class MinTreeHeap<E> extends BinaryTree implements PriorityQueue<E> {

public MinTreeHeap(Comparator<? super E> comp) {
  // store comp in a field of type Comparator<? super E>
  // or pass it over to other implementation code
  …
}
…
```

Comment: This makes perfect sense for (Curiously recurring pattern)[ http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Curiously_recurring_template_pattern&mobileaction=toggle_view_desktop]

Comment: Great. That helps a lot already. I also found, that it is enough to have `public class MinTreeHeap<T> implements PriorityQueue<T> {...}` but how do I change the constructor when it gets called in the way described above? `MinTreeHeap<Value> heap = new MinTreeHeap<>( new DefaultComparator<Value>() );`

Comment: @sebastian: like in the example at the bottom of my answer. You just have to replace `E` with `T`. If `DefaultComparator` does what I think (i.e. implement `Comparator`), it should fit.